# Retrieve The Password In Command Mode

Tags: 12.04

I Can't Current Password. How To Set New Password In Linux Command Line On Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Literally found this in 5 seconds. Try to do a little digging before asking!

That should do it.

[Reset Lost Password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)